# difference between pointer and address reference

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not sure how to call this two pointer differently so please correct my terms.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3]={10,20,30};
    int * ptr = &arr[0];// arr

    return 0;
}
```

is there some differences between arr and *ptr?
Both pointed at the same address, but what's the difference.

Comment: There's are 1000s of question on this site. Please do some search.

Comment: my bad , I don't know how to call arr and *ptr .

Comment: Maybe you call them pointers?

Comment: @ckruczek, no arrays and pointers are quite different until used in contexts where one decays to the other.

Comment: There is no "reference" in C.

Comment: array type decays to pointer to the first element in certain cases, just FYI.

Comment: can you address me to the duplicated question link? POW

Comment: [Is an array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an array and `ptr` is a pointer of type `int`.

There are differences . Let me list few

1. `sizeof(arr)` is different from `sizeof(ptr)`
2. You can do `ptr++` pointer operation using `ptr` whereas `arr++` is an invalid operation.

Going by your comment of what is the difference between pointer and array I have answered your question

```
int a = 10;
int b[5] = {1,2,3,45};
int *p = &a;
b = &a;  /* not valid */
```

`b` is a array and not a pointer so it can't hold address of a variable.

```
p = b;
p = p +1;

printf("%d\n",*p); /* valid as p is pointing to second element in the array */

b = b+1;
```

is not valid because array can't be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's not the most complete answer that could be given, but it gives no mis-information.

It may be worth nothing to the OP that *ptr is different from ptr. (*ptr = arr[0] = 10 whereas ptr = arr = &arr[0])

Comment: *(arr+1) is working also as *(ptr +1)

Comment: @kingyum *(arr +1) = arr[1] . What you have to note is *(a+i) = a[i]

Comment: why arr++ is not working?

Comment: arr++ is not same as *(arr + 1)

Comment: can you explain more about why arr++ is not valid?

Comment: @kingyum Does my update help?

Comment: yes, so the type is difference. and also is there any difference between arr[0]  and *ptr  other then the type? arr[0] is now allows arr[0]++

Comment: Gopi, this is personal question but what is your secret to study programming? and How long you been working with this kind of stuff? and I want to be a better programmer with lot of knowledge. reveal your secret

Comment: @kingyum Keep learning. I amalso learning. There is no such secret

Comment: @Gopi thanks for your help take care

Answer (score -1):

*'is there some differences between arr and *ptr'*

Yes, there is. For example `sizeof(*ptr)` is a size of `int` value, that is `sizeof(int)`, while `sizeof(arr)` is a size of the whole array and equals `3*sizeof(int)`.